Deploy Azure function App configuratios via Azure DevOps Pipeline
I want my Azure DevOps pipeline to deploy all the function app configs without manually entering them in the devops pipeline how to do that ?
We've C# code which is getting deployed on Azure function apps. But we're adding the configs of fucntion apps manually in azure devops pipeline.
As of now we're entering the configs in Azure function deploy task in pipeline, but I want it as it needs to come from source code directly without enteritng them in pipeline.
We need direction to understand how we can automate the config vaules by using ADO pipelines. Is this possible ?

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61598490/how-to-deploy-function-app-settings-to-azure-function-app-using-azure-devops-app

No Rui, here are also we're entering key1:value1 , key2:value2 manually in pipeline. I've 250+configs, should I add all these 250 configs manually ?? I don't want to do that...is there any other way which will directly deploy from source code ?? because those 250 configs won't change for env to env. they'll be static thorugh all env's from dev to prod.
Is there a way ?

@suryaTeja Based on your requirement, I have shared the script to read the appsettings in the appsettings.json file and set them in Azure Function app. You can check my answer.

You can add a task to run an Azure CLI script to edit app settings in bulk:
az webapp config appsettings set \
  --resource-group <group-name> \
  --name <app-name> \
  --settings "@settings.json"

The file format needed for settings.json is a JSON array of settings where the slot setting field is optional
[
  {
    "name": "key1",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "name": "key2",
    "value": "value2"
  }
]

For convenience, you can save existing settings into a JSON file with az webapp config appsettings list. The following example can be run in Bash:
# Save the settings
az webapp config appsettings list --name <app-name> --resource-group <group-name> > settings.json

# Edit the JSON file
...

# Update the app with the JSON file
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --settings @settings.json


This is fine but, is there any other way which will directly pull all the configs in appsettings.json file and deploy directly all those configs on function app ??

Hi Rui Jarimba, Finally i went with this solution. It's workign fine, Thanks

The appsettings.json file can not be directly used in the Azure CLI: az webapp config appsettings set.

is there any other way which will directly pull all the configs in appsettings.json file and deploy directly all those configs on function app ?

To meet your requirement, you can use script to loop the app settings value in the appsettings.json file. Then you can add them to an array and use it to the Azure CLI commnad.
Here is an example:
steps:


- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $json = Get-Content '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/AzureFunctionAppSettings/Startup/appsettings.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
      
      $appsettingnames =  $json.values | Get-Member | Where {$_.MemberType -like 'NoteProperty'} | Select-Object  -Property name
      
      $appsettingslist = @()

      ForEach ($appsettingname in $appsettingnames.name)
      {
        $appsettingvalue =  $json.values.$appsettingname

        $singleappsetting = "`"$appsettingname=$appsettingvalue`""

        $appsettingslist = $appsettingslist + $singleappsetting
      }

      echo $appsettingslist

      
      az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group resourcegroupname --name functionappname --settings $appsettingslist
  

Result sample:


Hi Kevin, thanks for sharing this, Eventhough I've not tried your solution but the solution provided by Rui below is working fine, we no need to loop thorugh the array as per Rui solution. Thanks
